# Passing a pointer to function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I need to know the difference between

```
int *testPointer  = NULL;
int a=10;
testPointer=&a;
testPointer->someFunc();
```

and

```
int *testPointer  = NULL;
int a=10;
testPointer=&a;
someFunc(testPointer);
```

Secondly which will better way of calling `someFunc` function, so that I can access data pointed by the pointer `testPointer` and maybe modify it.

Comment: `int` doesn't have `someFunc()` method...

Comment: The latter is *potentially* valid C++ code (dependent on `someFunc`'s argument list), the former isn't.

Comment: i can't understand what do you mean to say , when you use the word     method . i'm pretty new to C++

Comment: You should read a basic c++ book first. The term *method* is very fundamental to c++ and object oriented programming in general. Asking questions here without knowing the very basics of c++ will not get you anywhere because you'll never be able to see the big picture.

Comment: @user3690978: when calling a function this way `testPointer->someFunc();` assumes that testPointer points to an object of a class that has a memberfunction `somFunc()`.  In that case the `this` pointer of the object is passed to the function impilicitly.

Comment: @oxygene the book i'm referring to doesn't or hasn't yet used the word method. i'll make sure i get it

Comment: Which book is it? Is it a c++ book? Or just c?  You are using a method call in your sample code. Strange book to teach you something without naming it...

Comment: its C++ , the way ive formed the question is wrong.. the pointer is of a class .. after reading @stefaanv comment i understood my mistake and  i got a fair idea of what i was looking for ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I need to know the difference between
>
> ```
> int *testPointer  = NULL;
> int a=10;
> testPointer=&a;
> testPointer->someFunc();
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> int *testPointer  = NULL;
> int a=10;
> testPointer=&a;
> someFunc(testPointer);
> ```

First snippet, "testPointer->someFunc();" **will not compile**. "testPointer" is an int type variable, it does not have a method named "someFunc()".

Second snippet, **will compile**. it will call "someFunc()". This will work if "someFunc()" is declared as **"void someFunc(int*)"**

---

> Secondly which will better way of calling someFunc function, so that I
>   can access data pointed by the pointer testPointer and maybe modify
>   it.

The **second snippet** is the right way to call "someFunc()", and it will be able to modify value of the data pointed by "testPointer".

Answer (score 3):

In the first case:

```
testPointer->someFunc();
```

you are trying to call `testPointer`s function `someFunc()` wich it doesn't have because it is an `int`. 
In the second case:

```
someFunc(testPointer);
```

you are passing `testpointer` to function `someFunc()`